# Customization to get the shopping Cart at the right side of checkout steps?

Tags: checkout, cart, magento-1.9, custom-options, shopping-cart

I am working on a horizontal checkout and need to get the shopping on its right side.
something like this. Any possible way ?
thanks[image]

Comment: is it default magento checkout??

Comment: Its the default checkout with minor changes in styles.css to make it horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your layout file

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

You may need to play around with the css to make it fit your page.
If you need a different markup, then clone the template file `checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml` to `checkout/cart/checkout_sidebar.phtml` and replace `template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"` in the code above with `template="checkout/cart/checkout_sidebar.phtml"` and do your modifications in there.

Comment: Where can i find the layout file to copy paste that above code? Can you please explain this in a bit detail, I would really appreciate your help. Or you can pm me on facebook though https://www.facebook.com/ronika.kaur93
thanks!

Comment: the file is located in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml`

Comment: I copy paste the above code in the end of sidebar.phtml
but no luck. checkout is same as default !!